# Merge between two dataframes based on column with reference to the date

Tags: r

I have two data frames - one is a transaction dataframe which shows the item number and the date of transaction. The other is a price dataframe which shows the price of the products (changing over time).

I need to merge the correct price to from the price dataframe to the transaction dataframe. Mock example below:

```
transaction_df<-data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("18/12/2013", "12/09/2019", "15/8/2017", "09/01/2018"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), Item = c(8002, 8004, 8001, 8002))

item_price<-data.frame(item=c(8000, 8000, 8001, 8002, 8002, 8002, 8003, 8003, 8004, 8004), date=as.Date(c("17/02/2015", "09/11/2017", "01/02/2012", "30/09/2012", "12/05/2017", "23/11/2019", "20/01/2013", "18/03/2017", "07/02/2018", "19/10/2019"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), price=c(12.47, 13.20, 35.99, 21.45, 20.83, 20.55, 44.60, 45.00, 5.35, 6.80))

result<-data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("18/12/2013", "12/09/2019", "15/8/2017", "09/01/2018"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), Item = c(8002, 8004, 8001, 8002), result=c(21.45, 5.35, 35.99, 20.83))
```

The prices are the *price from* i.e. if there is only one price, that's the price, or if the transaction took place today the appropriate price would be the most recent one.

Of course I can use merge() to copy prices across, but haven't figured out out to take account of the date. I started to write a loop which would do it (very roughly) but I have a massive amount of data, and I'm sure there must be a cleaner way of doing it - perhaps using filter().

The machine I'm working from doesn't have access to packages unfortunately, so DPLYR isn't an option, though I'd be interested to see if/how it could be done using transform().

Thanks so much for any help :)

Comment: It seems to be the date in transaction and date in item is not matched.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear. If the price dataframe only contains price changes. The correct price will be the most recent previous price change. I have thousands of price changes over a window of decades - so while I could make a dataframe for each item/each day it would be alot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues with your question

1. There are no common dates in both datasets. Thus, I'm not sure how you intend to merge using that variable.
2. Variable names are case sensitive - you have "Item" and "item", and "Date" and "date"

When you've sorted out those issues, this should work

```
mergedfile <- merge(transaction_df , item_price , by=c("Item","Date"))
```